# The "twocol" plugin does not exist

Tags: 8, panels

After updating the Panels module to 8.x-4.2, I got the following error whenever I submit any form in the site.

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "twocol" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52 of /var/www/test_site/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).

Comment: Did you clear the cache and run any db updates?

Comment: Yes, I did clear the cache "drush cache-regenerate"  also run the database update "drush updatedb -y"

The problem still exists.

I'm using Drupal 8.4.0

Comment: Have the same problem here...